# How can I update_option on wp plugin update?

Tags: wordpress

I've built a WordPress and it's already live. On the new version, I've to set some options in DB. Right now I've set them using `update_option` on `register_activation_hook`. It works for new plugin installation

But if someone is already using the plugin, `register_activation_hook` is not called on the plugin update. What is the recommended way to set some settings like `update_option` on plugin update? Can I use `upgrader_process_complete`?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to disable, then re-enable the plugin using 
register_activation_hook and register_deactivation_hook (to clean up after yourself) for this type of thing. Back up your database and test in local and dev environments first.

Comment: but register_activation_hook hook is not called during the update process. So will that work?

Comment: You may need to create an update function as described here regarding table structure changes for a plugin. https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins#Adding_an_Upgrade_Function